# Editing Ubuntu official documentation pages

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

Maybe I wasn’t rigorous enough in reading the page, but I can’t edit the Ubuntu Wiki Official Documentation.

I logged in using my UbuntuOne Account and using my Launchpad Account but still I can’t edit the page.

Let us take an example on this page:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster

I found an error in the `keychain` set code instruction on MPICH Cluster arrangement. The instruction asks us to put some code in the `~/.bashrc` file. It was written as:

```
if type keychain >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  keychain --nogui -q id_rsa
  [ -f ~/.keychain/${HOSTNAME}-sh ] && . ~/.keychain/${HOSTNAME}-sh
  [ -f ~/.keychain/${HOSTNAME}-sh-gpg ] && . ~/.keychain/${HOSTNAME}-sh-gpg
```

We should add `fi` to complete this code. Otherwise it will give us error. I want to add that fix. I also want to add a comment that this action should be done in the master machine, not in the helper machine (I prefer to use “helper machine” instead of “slave machine”).

Maybe somebody can help to do this. Thank you

Comment: Nope, is not here that you should ask, I could edit the page nonetheles.

Comment: @Braiam : Thanks for the effort. And also thanks for those who had been so kind to migrate the question to the proper place.

Comment: What do you mean "still couldn't edit the page"? What does it say when you try?

Comment: @Seth : First I select `Login to edit`. Afterwards, I should authenticate that I will login with my **UbuntuOne**. The page was redirected to the selected page that I want to edit. But I experience that I can't edit. May be I miss some step or something. So that was my experience, @Seth

Comment: After logging in you need to go back to the page and click edit again. http://i.imgur.com/D4BGSXY.png Did you do that?

Comment: It also looks like Braiam made the changes for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK After some explanation from several community member, I can summarize the step how to edit

> Ubuntu official documentation pages

by practice. There are probably other procedures in accordance with this.

(For the official Guidance is just available in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WikiGuide)

1. Click `Login to edit`, when you are in the page that you want to edit.
   [image]
2. Login to or sign up for your Ubuntu One account.
   [image]
3. Accept your personal data request by clicking `Yes, Log me in`. 
   [image]
4. After you are redirected to the User Documentation Page, you can search the article you want to edit. It took around 10 second in my case to be redirected. 
   [image]
   [image]
5. Finally, you will have an `edit` button to modify the page.
   [image]
   [image]

Good day!

Comment: I should not forget to add @Seth remark : "In some cases, after logging in you need to go back to the page and click edit again." Thanks