# Very outdated page at wiki.ubuntu.com: What can you do?

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

I found a very outdated page at wiki.ubuntu.com:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ScreenCasts/Istanbul

The "Istanbul" Screencast software looks dead. The homepage is gone, and not update since 2007.

The wiki page is protected. I can't delete it.

What can I do to clean up the wiki?

(the whole area (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ScreenCasts/) is outdated. Kazam works fine).

Comment: Related: [Editing Ubuntu official documentation pages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417236/editing-ubuntu-official-documentation-pages), [Talk pages (or feedback forms) at Ubuntu wikis](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661712/talk-pages-or-feedback-forms-at-ubuntu-wikis)

Comment: +1 for canonical post. Even [the official WikiGuide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WikiGuide) does not seem to explain on how to inform the outdated pages, without having to register and contribute directly. A simple feedback form with captcha to prevent spam would probably do the job.

Comment: @clearkimura I couldn't agree with you more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are members of the Ubuntu news team who have rights to edit the wiki. I have rights to edit wiki pages, so if nobody else gets to it before me, I'll take a look at that one when I get home this evening. Right now I'm on my phone at work.

If you'd like to bring it to their attention directly until I get to it this evening, or inquire about joining the news team yourself, you can join the #ubuntu-news channel in the Ubuntu IRC server.

Comment: These pages about creating is several years outdated. No need to hurry. I guess you know this, but maybe it helps someone: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_management#The_Eisenhower_Method

Comment: I think the basic/fundamental issue is that you can't tell the news team that a page is outdated. I guess a lot of people see outdated information in the wiki. These humans will look at the outdated page, then ask themselves "why does nobody care for this?" and then they leave the page. It would be wise to lower the barriers for feedback.

Comment: It's my understanding that it used to be wide open to anyone with an Ubuntu One or Launchpad account. I had edit rights years ago and had to request them back to update one of the pages I'd created. Apparently they started getting a lot of spam traffic/articles and had to lock it down. That's what I was told anyway.

Comment: I think providing feedback and editing the page are two different things. It is easy to say "Hey, ubuntu wiki team, this page looks outdated". But editing the page is way harder. Only few people are brave enough the actually update the page. If you want feedback, you should lower the barrier, to make it easy for people to provide hints. Requesting an actual change from an average web user who sees the outdated page is (my opinion) way too much.

Comment: Just to update, I removed mention of Istanbul and added mention of OBS Studio, and since OBS is in the official repos and on snapcraft, I created a new page about OBS that summarizes it. The link on that "Screencasts" page for OBS takes you to that page. I'll see about reviewing the rest of the content on and related to that Screencasts page later.