# Linux kernel flavours in modern releases

Tags: kernel

Nowadays (18.04+) there are much more kernel flavours, and not all of them are well described. I see those ones:

- `generic`, the default one, with possible `-hwe` branch;
- `virtual` — same as `generic` but excluding `modules-extra`. Can have `-hwe` branch too;
- `kvm`;
- `azure`, `aws`, `gcp`, `gke` — targeting cloud providers;
- `oem` — who is that?;
- `oracle` — what Oracle systems?

So, how do I choose? For example, VPS probably doesn't need `generic` kernel, `virtual` would require way less valuable disk space, but maybe `kvm` is even better? What is the difference in the first place?

Wiki has a page on the subject (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/Flavours), but it is way outdated.

Comment: This is a better article but I don't think it answers your "how do I choose" question. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

Comment: @OrganicMarble that's really a nice one that explains HWE stack, but yeah, not the kernel flavours.

Comment: @LapshinDmitry There is always 'roll your own' as well...

Comment: Given the example of VPS (Virtual Private Server), I guess that depends on what type of VPS in use? The [tag info for 'vps'](https://askubuntu.com/tags/vps/info) noted that "[the] most common VPS types are OpenVZ, KVM, Xen and VMWare." For KVM, Ubuntu has the `linux-kvm` with [prepackaged on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-kvm/) and [meta package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-kvm&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) for 16.04 and newer.

Comment: Related to outdated wiki: [Very outdated page at wiki.ubuntu.com: What can you do?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1153543/37165)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ubuntu Kernel Team has a [dedicated web site](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/reports/) that links to various reports on kernel packages and versions on Ubuntu. From there, see [package versions](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/reports/versions.html) to quickly view what kernels are currently maintained on available Ubuntu releases.

List of kernel flavours prepackaged for Ubuntu:

- [`linux`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux) that provides generic kernels (12.04+)
- [`linux-hwe`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe) that provides Ubuntu [LTS enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)
- [`linux-hwe-edge`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-edge) has kernels newer than `linux-hwe`
- [`linux-kvm`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-kvm) that provides kernels for virtual systems (16.04+)
- [`linux-aws`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-aws) that provides kernels for Amazon Web Services (14.04+)
- [`linux-aws-edge`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-aws-edge) has kernels newer than `linux-aws` (16.04+)
- [`linux-aws-hwe`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-aws-hwe) may provide kernels newer than `linux-aws-edge`
- [`linux-azure`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-azure) that provides kernels for Azure systems (14.04+)
- [`linux-euclid`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-euclid) that provides kernels for Intel Euclid systems (16.04)
- [`linux-gcp`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-gcp) that provides kernels for Google Cloud Platform (16.04+)
- [`linux-gcp-edge`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-gcp-edge) may provide kernels newer than `linux-gcp` (18.04)
- [`linux-oem`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem) that provides kernels for [OEM](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/OEM) systems including Dell, Lenovo, Acer, etc. (16.04+)
- [`linux-oem-osp1`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1) has kernels newer than `linux-oem` (18.04+)
- [`linux-oracle`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oracle) that provides kernels for Oracle systems (16.04+)
- [`linux-oracle-edge`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oracle-edge) has kernels newer than `linux-oracle` (no release yet)
- [`linux-raspi2`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi2/) that provides kernels for the BCM2709 architecture (16.04+)
- [`linux-snapdragon`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-snapdragon/) that provides kernels for the Qualcomm Snapdragon 410c architecture (16.04+)

What have been listed here excludes some meta and transitional packages that are not found in the [package versions](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/reports/versions.html), but otherwise found in the [Ubuntu Packages Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/). Each description has been adapted from the Ubuntu packages or alternatively description from the `apt-cache show <package>` command.

> So, how do I choose?

Admittedly, there is no definite guide for choosing which kernels to use case by case.

End-users usually do not need to choose a different Linux kernel, for example, when installing Ubuntu Desktop in a virtual machine--it will just work. If the [provided download images](https://ubuntu.com/download) do not fulfill the needs, and instead user had to decide which kernels to use, then most likely the user needs to ask whomever that provides the service to run Ubuntu. They should have the answer.

> What is the difference in the first place?

In one word: Optimization.

End-users usually do not go as far to find out what things are optimized for each and every kernels prepackaged for Ubuntu. There is no easy way to know what is the difference in the first place, unless the documentation was done properly. There is one place to find out: Changelog.

The changelogs are specific to each package and the currently supported releases. For example, [the changelog for `linux` in bionic](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/linux/+changelog) has noted more changes related to optimization for various platforms in general, whilst [the changelog for `linux-kvm` in bionic](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/linux-kvm/+changelog) has noted more changes related to the containers (OS-level virtualization).

**TL;DR** End-users do not need to choose and instead use whichever kernels included in the Ubuntu images. Else, look for someone with the knowledge--the service provider or whomever that is.

Comment: That's a really great answer, thank you!

Comment: On the subject of not choosing because vendor has put a thought in it: I have seen a lot of VPS running 300MB -generic kernel just because, I belive, only so much people actually know the difference. So, actually putting guidelines to check kernel to be used could help the community.

Comment: I guess the most effective way to know the difference is to download source packages and diff between the config files.

Comment: We're in 2023, and there's a weird one in the list: `nvidia` flavor. What does this mean? Is it for nvidia chipsets, or for anyone that has a `nvidia` graphics card?

Comment: The package says: "Linux kernel image for Nvidia systems." - so `nvidia` flavor is probably as was most likely, the first, chipsets.